# Detect PHP version in Travis

Tags: travis-ci

In my Travis file I have several PHP versions and a script entry like this:

```
php:
    - 5.6
    - 5.5
    - 5.4
    - 5.3

script:
    - export CFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror"
    - phpize #and lots of other stuff here.
    - make
```

I want to run the `export CFLAGS` line only when the PHP version matches 5.6.

I could theoretically do that with a nasty hack to detect the PHP version from the command line, but how can I do this through the Travis configuration script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either use shell conditionals to do this:

```
php:
    - 5.6
    - 5.5
    - 5.4
    - 5.3

script:
    - if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "5.6" ]]; then export CFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror"; fi
    - phpize #and lots of other stuff here.
    - make
```

Or use the build matrix with [explicit inclusions](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Explicit-inclusion-of-jobs-into-the-build-matrix):

```
matrix:
    include:
      - php: 5.6
        env: CFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror"
      - php: 5.5
        env: CFLAGS=""
      - php: 5.4
        env: CFLAGS=""
      - php: 5.3
        env: CFLAGS=""

script:
    - phpize #and lots of other stuff here.
    - make
```

The latter is probably what you're looking for, the former is a little less verbose.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the environment variable TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION is actually available to any bash script that is called in the 'script' block. As the condition is actually a bit more complicated, I've moved it to a separate script called through ". ./cflags.sh"