# Travis if statement does not execute

Tags: bash, travis-ci

For some reason when I use an `if` statement it will not execute the configure for it. Here is my full `travis.yml` below.

**travis.yml:**

```
language: php
php:
    - '5.6.32'
    - '7.0.26'
    - '7.1.12'
    - '7.2.0'
os:
    - windows
    - linux
git:
    depth: 1
matrix:
    fast_finish: true
sudo: false
before_install:
    - if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2.0" ]]; then git clone -b stable https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.git; fi
    - if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2.0" ]]; then cd libsodium && sudo ./configure && sudo make check && sudo make install && cd ..; fi
install:
    - if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2.0" ]]; then pecl install libsodium; fi
    - if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2.0" ]]; then echo "extension=sodium.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini; fi
    - travis_retry composer install --no-interaction
    - wget -c -nc --retry-connrefused --tries=0 https://github.com/satooshi/php-coveralls/releases/download/v1.0.1/coveralls.phar
    - chmod +x coveralls.phar
    - php coveralls.phar --version
before_script:
    - mkdir -p build/logs
    - ls -al
script:
    - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml
after_success:
    - travis_retry php coveralls.phar -v
branches:
    only: master
cache:
    directories:
        - vendor
        - $HOME/.cache/composer
```

So for some reason

```
- if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2.0" ]]; then 
     export git clone -b stable https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.git;
 fi
```

does not work and I got this solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686068/8144086)

My goal is to execute certain lines on certain PHP version.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Why are you prefixing every command with "export"? That doesn't make any sense. Export is used to make variables or functions available in subshells.

Comment: I removed `export` it still does not run, either way that is not causing the problem.

Comment: If you post a link to your travis build it should be a bit easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: I found the mistake you made and edited my Answer, but still I would recommend using a seperate a separate script file if you want to do a lot of scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

you extracted the first 3 characters of the `TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION`and compared it with 5 characters.. of course that doesn't work. you can either try:

```
if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:5} == "7.2.0" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2" ]]
```

**END EDIT**

I had some problems running scripts inside the Travis config file, since i wanted blank lines and comments and Travis got confused with that. So in general i would recommend to do the scripting in a separate bash file.

The easiest way is to do all the bash scripting in a script file and use the script files in your travis.yml

```
before_install: ./travis-scripts/before_install.sh
```

Now you can write your scripts with the bash syntax and they work right away.

If you still want to write the scripts inside the travis file, try that (not everything worked for me everytime):

```
install: >
    if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2" ]]; then pecl install libsodium; fi;
    if [[ ${TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION:0:3} == "7.2" ]]; then echo "extension=sodium.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini; fi;
    travis_retry composer install --no-interaction;
    wget -c -nc --retry-connrefused --tries=0 https://github.com/satooshi/php-coveralls/releases/download/v1.0.1/coveralls.phar;
    chmod +x coveralls.phar;
    php coveralls.phar --version;
```

Or leave it as it is and only put the if statements in quotes.

Comment: Thank you i did not know what `:0:3` ment until now. I am learning. :)